# Adding PeriodicCallback to already running IOLoop instance

Tags: python, tornado

I want to create a simple scheduler in Tornado, where along the course of the app, some job with a (time,callback) is generated dynamically, for example,

Send a push notification 30 mins before an event, 
but this reminder is created only after the job is created by the server, which may be through a POST request.

I wanted to achieve this through PeriodicCallback, but I read that IOLoop.start() must be called after the PeriodicCallback is created. How can I add PeriodicCallback to already running IOLoop or is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no requirement that PeriodicCallbacks be started before the IOLoop. You can start them while the IOLoop is running. You have to schedule *something* before calling `IOLoop.start()` since that will run forever, but whatever you schedule on the IOLoop can go on to schedule other stuff.

Comment: This was the right answer, but ultimately I ended up using the APScheduler library (https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) ,which was better suited to my needs and works very well with Tornado (they have even a TornadoScheduler). Just putting it out there for those who aren't aware of it.